# UI prefabs are instantiated below the canvas

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am trying to copy the Zelda health system. The code looks really fine and works fine.

But the heart containers are placed wrong. They get instantiated below the canvas.

This is the important code, the heart containers are correct, just at the wrong position.

The calculation of x and y is correct, but on the canvas it is not.

```
  private Transform healthBar = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("HealthController").transform; // container for the heartContainers

    private GameObject healthWrapperObject = Resources.Load("HealthContainer") as GameObject; // the backgroundImage and parent of the heart

    private List<Image> healthContainers = new List<Image>(); // list of hearts for later usages

    private int maxHealth = 6;
    private int currentHealth;

    private int healthPerHealthContainer = 4; // 4 lifepoints per heart
    private int healthContainersPerRow = 5; // 5 hearts per row

    private int healthContainerStartPositionX = 0; // Healthbar starts at 0 on x
    private int healthContainerStartPositionY = 0; // Healthbar starts at 0 on y

    private int healthContainerSpacingX = 10; // horizontal spacing
    private int healthContainerSpacingY = -10; // vertical spacing

    private void Start()
    {
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
        InitializeHealthBar();
    }

    public void InitializeHealthBar()
    {
        int neededHealthContainers = maxHealth % healthPerHealthContainer == 0 ? maxHealth / healthPerHealthContainer : maxHealth / healthPerHealthContainer + 1; // Calculate the needed container count
        int counter = 0; // counts the hearts per row 
        int x = healthContainerStartPositionX; // horizontal position of the heartContainer
        int y = healthContainerStartPositionY; // vertical position of the heartContainer

        for (int i = 0; i < neededHealthContainers; i++)
        {
            counter++;

            if (counter >= healthContainersPerRow) // start a new line after 5 hearts per row
            {
                x = healthContainerStartPositionX; // move back to the left
                y += healthContainerSpacingY; // go for the next line
                counter = 0; // reset the counter
            }
            else
                x += healthContainerSpacingX; // place the new container right next to the previous

            Transform newHealthContainerTransform = Instantiate(healthWrapperObject, new Vector2(x, y), healthWrapperObject.transform.rotation).transform; // create the healthContainer parent / backgroundImage
            newHealthContainerTransform.SetParent(healthBar); // take the container and make it a child of the healthBar
            healthContainers.Add(newHealthContainerTransform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>()); // get the heart of the heartContainer and add it to the heartList
        }
    }
```

I added the transform settings for the healthBar, the healthContainer / backgroundImage and the heart ("healthfill").

On all 3 elements I pressed Strg+Alt and Shift for anchoring them.

The heartcontainter should be added to the healthbar, the heart is a child of the heartcontainer and is set to stretch (it should be the same size as its parent)

Why are the UI prefab Objects instantiated below the canvas?

[image: Ingame]

[image: HealthBar]

[image: HealthContainer]

[image: HealthObjekt]

Comment: Sorry that I can't be of more help, but have you considered asking this in unity forums? Can't help but feel that this might be the wrong place for these sort of questions... :/

Comment: Hm no, actually I did not ..

Comment: No worries. I won't downvote you or anything, just thought you'd be better off on a more specific forum. Good luck! :)

Comment: thank you, I really hope someone got an idea for me

Comment: This question is valid here. What is the problem and what is the question? I think this is why you don't have any answer yet.

Comment: The health containers are created below the canvas and not in the top left corner

Comment: @Question3r Got it. It's even in the title. Kept looking in the body of the question

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are getting something like this:

[image]

You fix this by pass `false` to the second parameter of the `SetParent` function. By doing this, you will make the Transform keep its local orientation rather than its global orientation.

Simply replace :

```
newHealthContainerTransform.SetParent(healthBar);
```

with:

```
newHealthContainerTransform.SetParent(healthBar, false)
```

---

You can also set the parent Object and make the instantiated Object's Transform keep its local orientation in the `Instantiate` function. The only disadvantage of this is that you now have to set the position of object in another line of code instead of the `Instantiate` function like before.

```
Transform newHealthContainerTransform = Instantiate(healthWrapperObject, healthBar, false).transform;
newHealthContainerTransform.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition3D = new Vector2(x, y);
```

---

When moving a UI Object you should be modifying it's `RectTransform` variables instead of the `Transform` variables.

Below are other useful variables that determines where to position the UI:

These are `anchoredPosition`, `anchoredPosition3D`, `anchorMax` and `anchorMin` which can be modified with:

```
yourUIObj.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = ...
yourUIObj.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition3D = ...
yourUIObj.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchorMax = ...
yourUIObj.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchorMin = ...
```

Comment: yes, exactly what I was looking for! I thought no one could fix this :D thank you very much, awesome!